# method taking a class parameter

Tags: object-oriented, python, uml, parameters

I have recently begun studying UML. All is going fine so far until I saw the following:

[image: Class Point2D]

This is a class Called Point2D
It has 2 attributes which are x, type float and y, type float.
It has 3 methods

1. __init __(takes parameters 'x' and 'y', both of which are float) returns nothing
2. distance (takes parameter 'target' which has the type class ???) returns a float
3. display() returns nothing

I have no problem of reading these but my issue arose with the method 'distance', especially on how to interpret the parameter 'target' being Point2D

How should this be interpreted?

Python reconstruction:

```
class Point2D:
x = float
y = float

def display(self):
    print('coordinate x ' + str(self.x) + ', coordinate y ' + str(self.y))

def distance(self, target):
    gap = sqrt(abs(target.x-self.x)**2 + abs(target.y-self.y)**2)
    # target is still an enigma but the code above should describe what 
    # distance is supposed to do


def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.y = float(y)
    self.x = float(x)
```

Comment: What do you think this could mean? Perhaps you could write some pseudocode to show how that method might be used or how it could be implemented.

Comment: The UML shows the Point2D used as an object that holds 2 properties (x,y), I am not a Python developer, but the code does not reflect the UML. Note that in UML you can decide on the level of detail you want to use, in many cases, the UML is not used to produce code, rather to show the overall structure.

Comment: @NoChance that actually makes some sense eg point2d1 = Point2D(5.5,1.6) and point2d2 = Point2D(-2.3,-4.6)

Comment: Distance is usually a function with two parameters, a x and a y, say. Now, in OO, instead of writing d = distance(x,y) we would do something like d= x.distance(y) (though I personally hate that formulation. Pure math functions are really ugly in pure OO). So in UML, what would the specification of distance look like?

Comment: Your thinking is inconsistent. Can you explain precisely and step-by-step, why you think that the types of the parameters of `__init__` are `float` and `float`? Now, look at the steps you took and apply *exactly the same steps* to `distance`. What is the type of the `target` parameter?

Comment: *"takes parameter 'target' which has the type class ???"* - `s/???/Point2D`. That's what it says; the method expects `target` to be the same type as `self`. Note that the class attributes `x = float` and `y = float` seem strange; what are they for?

Comment: Your code example was *not* showing what distance is supposed to do, I took the freedom to fix that. And the fact you have problems of understanding this is most probably not a programming or softwareengineering or UML problem. "distance" here means the so-called [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between the point "self" and the point "target". If the Wikipedia entry is too formal for you, google for that term, I am sure you will find a simpler explanation somewhere.

Comment: I appreciate all the input but I'm dumbfounded on the dislikes this question gets.. I did not offend anyone right? Neither was it my intention to post a dumb question because I just literally asked what was on my mind

Comment: I didn't downvote but my guess people downvote because you ask about a fundamental thing. I would treat it as a signal that something is wrong with the teaching you undergo (a course, a book or a lecture, never mind). On the other hand sometimes things are so obvious to those who know them, we tend to forget they may not be to those, who are fresh in the topic. That's why I believe this kind of questions should have answers as well. Another potential reason is you didn't show the effort you've put in finding the answer but again, for this kind of question I'm not sure if it's really relevant.

Comment: @CCG: from your question it is really hard to understand where your actual problem is, and though people asked for clarification,  we cannot see much effort so far to clarify things, though you got some good recommendations (like the one from Jörg W Mittag). Unclear question get downvotes on this site, that's quite normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a type of parameter, attribute etc. can be a class. Simply speaking you need to pass an object of the right type, in your case an object being instance of class Point2D.